# Wamp online (green icon) but can´t execute a php script

Tags: wamp

Wampserver online (icon is green), phpmyadmin loads but can´t manage to work a php test script.

First let me explain that port 80 was taken by microsoft - IIS / 8.0 , this obliged me to reconfigure : wampmanager.tpl and http.conf to port 8080.

As `http://localhost:8080/` is typed on the browser, it finds normally the Server Configuration Apache Version : 2.4.4 PHP Version : 5.4.12 and PHPMYADMIN loads as well.
I tried to run a very simple php script to test the server but it hasn´t worked.
I saved it to the folder C:\wamp\www , typed on the browser `http://localhost:8080/www/test_wamp.php` resulting in :

```
The requested URL /www/teste_wamp.php was not found on this server.
```

Can someone please sugggest me a possible solution ?

Comment: Try http://localhost:8080/test_wamp.php - you shouldn't need the `www` as WAMP, by default, starts there.

Comment: Had no idea , it has worked , thanks.